# Find the number of elements with a certain class within a div

Tags: jquery

How do I count all the elements in the containing div with the class ‘selected’?

My Jquery attempt:

```
$('.list').click(function(){
   check_no = $(this).closest("div").find('.selected').length;
   alert(check_no);
)};
```

Also tried

```
check_no = $(this).closest("div").children('.selected').length;
```

But it always says 0.

HTML

```
   <div id=1>
        <ul>
            <li class="list all">ALL</li>
            <li class="list selected">1</li>
            <li class="list">2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="list selected">3</li>
            <li class="list selected">4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="list">5</li>
            <li class="list">6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id=2>
        <ul>
            <li class="list all">ALL</li>
            <li class="list selected">1</li>
            <li class="list">2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="list selected">3</li>
            <li class="list">4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="list">5</li>
            <li class="list">6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So if I click on a class list within div id 1, I want to find the number of li's with class selected.

Comment: Can you share problem fiddle??

Comment: post more code please, what $(this) refers to? take a look http://jsbin.com/wosaxovi/1/edit

Comment: Your attempt works as expected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U8w4T/)

Comment: your code works fine, just a typo i guess, )}; should be }); http://jsbin.com/wosaxovi/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

your jquery

```
$('.list').on('click',function(){
    var check_no=$(this).closest("div").find('.selected').length;
   alert(check_no);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/7nrAR/1/)

if you want to find only **li with class selected** then your jquery would be

```
$('.list').on('click',function(){
    var check_no=$(this).closest("div").find('li.selected').length;
   alert(check_no);
});
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/7nrAR/3/)

Comment: Hmm, ok, yes that is working for you, I need to investigate further.

Comment: you have updated your question. and now your code is working fine .

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have some conflicting code, or I'm not understanding properly. This is working fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/UkD69/

I see you have updated your question. The code you have there works... I think you might not have been putting it in the domready function. See http://jsfiddle.net/UkD69/4/ and note the surrounding `$(function(){ [code] });`

```
$(function(){

    $("li").on("click", function(){

        check_no = $(this).closest("div").find('.selected').length;
        alert(check_no);

    });

});
```

Or, are you wanting this to run without an event? `$(this)` refers to the element that was attached to an event handler and caught by a function (as with my example).

This will check each `div` for the number of `.selected` classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/UkD69/1/

Answer (score 0):

you confused the brackets. so it will not work in your context

change

```
$('.list').click(function(){
   check_no = $(this).closest("div").find('.selected').length;
   alert(check_no);
)};
```

to

```
$('.list').click(function(){
   check_no = $(this).closest("div").find('.selected').length;
   alert(check_no);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be ok.

```
    $('.list').on('click',function(){
       var check_no = $(this).closest("div").find('.selected').length;
       alert(check_no);
    });
```

Try it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2VeW/)